# Unexpected error about DateTime type

Tags: sql-server, datetime, types, datetime2

I have a .aspx page for adding new product include the following field:

```
ID, Name, DateTime, Price
```

and it run well at localhost but when I publish it and up to the server, then I get the following error:

```
System.Data.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the InnerException for details. ---> System.ArgumentException: The version of SQL Server in use does not support datatype 'datetime2'

Localhost: SQL Server 2008 R2
Server: SQL Server 2005 Express
```

Although I generate the database to SQL 2005 format and make sure that there is no 'datetime2' datatype but the error is still here. I don't know why. Please give me a hand.

Any helps would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you googled for this error? Did not those solutions suite you? "Open your EDMX in a file editor (or “open with…” in Visual Studio and select XML Editor). At the top you will find the storage model and it has an attribute ProviderManifestToken"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're using Entity Framework and have built the EDMX against a SQL Server 2008 database. To fix:

Right click on your .edmx file and click "Open With" then select "XML Editor" to edit the XML. Add the following attribute to the `<Schema>` tag:

```
ProviderManifestToken="2005"
```

This will instruct the Entity Framework to be compatible with SQL Server 2005.